# Ambiguous process calcChecksum

Tags: module, arduino

CONTEXT 
I'm using a code written to work with a GPS module that connects to the Arduino through serial communication. The module starts each packet with a header (0xb5, 0x62), continues with the information you requested and ends with to bytes of checksum, CK_A, and CK_B. I don't understand the code that calculates that checksum. More info about the algorithm of checksum (8-Bit Fletcher Algorithm) in the module protocol (https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/u-blox7-V14_ReceiverDescriptionProtocolSpec_%28GPS.G7-SW-12001%29_Public.pdf), page 74 (87 with index).

MORE INFO
Just wanted to understand the code, it works fine. In the UBX protocol, I mentioned there is also a piece of code that explains how it works (isn't write in c++)

```
struct NAV_POSLLH {
//Here goes the struct
};

NAV_POSLLH posllh;

void calcChecksum(unsigned char* CK) {
 memset(CK, 0, 2);
 for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(NAV_POSLLH); i++) {
  CK[0] += ((unsigned char*)(&posllh))[i];
  CK[1] += CK[0];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provide, you can find a link to RFC 1145, containing that `Fletcher 8 bit` algorithm as well and explaining

> It can be shown that at the end of the loop A will contain the 8-bit
>   1's complement sum of all octets in the datagram, and that B will
>   contain (n)*D[0] + (n-1)*D[1] + ... + D[n-1].

n = sizeof byte D[];
*Quote adjusted to C syntax*

Try it with a couple of bytes, pen and paper, and you'll see :)

Comment: i don't undestand this line of code: `CK[0] += ((unsigned char*)(&posllh))[i];`

Comment: that's standard C: `x += y;` means `x = x+y;` . 
`((unsigned char*)(&posllh))` means: treat the address of posllh as a byte pointer. A pointer and an array are very similar. Anything else unclear?

Comment: THANKS! altough I continue without undestanding ' memset(CK, 0, 2);' and most of the code that I havn't posted.

Comment: @Juan, you should be able to google `memset` . The Arduino language is C++ (with C as just an early subset). "Clear two bytes of CK with 0".